# Return JSON from PHP script

Tags: php, json

I know that there is many content from this kind of topic but it's quite strange what's happening in my case.

The fact is that this was working without problems and suddenly it does not return anything. `$data` and `$postsInCat` has the desired content but when echoed, the received response is empty.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include "wp-blog-header.php";
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 20,
              'post_type'      => 'post',
              'paged'          => $paged,
              'nopaging'       => false,
              'cat'            => $_GET['author']
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

$data = array();
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->id              = $post->ID;
    $obj->title           = $post->post_title;
    $obj->excerpt         = substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 250).'...';
    $obj->slug            = str_replace('http://187.38.230.170/', '', get_permalink($post->ID));
    $obj->author_name     = get_user_by('id', $post->post_author)->user_login;
    $obj->featured_image  = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'post-thumbnails') );
    $obj->date            = new DateTime($post->post_date);
    $obj->date            = $obj->date->format("F d, Y");

    array_push($data, $obj);
endwhile;

$postsInCat = get_term_by('id', $_GET['author'], 'category');
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data, 'n_resultados' => $postsInCat->count));
?>
```

If I print `$data` with `print_r` function, it prints the whole content.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: It is possible to have non utf-8 characters? Because `json_encode` will return null if you try on wrong charset. only utf-8 is supported.

Comment: Check the JSON Errors using [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). Possibly there's a character which cannot be put inside JSON.

Comment: @PraveenKumar. Hi, yes, there is a malformed UTF-8 characters. How can I mend this error? The content is in MySQL and it setup as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the JSON Errors using [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). Possibly there's a character which cannot be put inside JSON. I encountered a same issue and I used this code:

```
<?php
    function utf8ize($d) {
        if (is_array($d)) {
            foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
                $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
            }
        } else if (is_string ($d)) {
            return utf8_encode($d);
        }
        return $d;
    }
?>
```

You can make something like:

```
$array = utf8ize($array);
```